# Routing between LANs on an EdgerouterX

Tags: networking, router, routing, ubiquiti

My apologies if this is a stupid question. I am trying to get an EdgerouterX set up in my home network and learn some practical networking at the same time. Currently, I have connected to the EdgerouterX and done the initial setup using the WAN+2LAN configuration wizard.

On the router: Eth0 is connected to an ASUS WIFI Router (I'm experimenting with this for now, though eventually I plan to connect eth0 directly to my modem and run the ASUS through the Edgerouter). The ASUS LAN network is 192.168.50.0/24 and eth0 has dhcp enabled with IP 192.168.50.55.

eth1 is on its own LAN: 192.168.10.0/24 - it's IP is 192.168.10.1 and my PC is connected here,

Eth 2-4 are a second LAN: 192.168.20.0/24 over the switch0 interface with IP 192.168.20.1.

Currently, I can ping and ssh into the Edgerouter from my PC. From the Edgerouter, I can ping 8.8.8.8 and get a response.

From my PC, I ping 8.8.8.8 and I get 'ping: sendto: no route to host' and Timeout.

In the Edgerouter I have the following routes already configured:

Destination.  Next Hop.  Interface.  Route Type  In FIB

0.0.0.0/0    192.168.50.1 eth0.      static.     yes

127.0.0.0/8                lo.        connected.  yes

192.168.10.0/24            eth1.      connected   yes

192.168.20.0/24            switch0    connected.  yes

192.168.50.0/24            eth0       connected.  yes

In NAT there is a masquerade to eth0 configure for all protocols.
The only firewall rules set up are WAN_In for eth0 and WAN_LOCAL for eth0. If I am understanding them correctly, neither should impact what I am trying to do. However, I tried setting both rules to 'Accept all' and found no difference in the above behavior. I have set them back.

The behavior makes me think that the router does not have a route from the 192.168.10.0/24 subnet to the 192.168.50.0/24 subnet. However, I would think that for a ping to 8.8.8.8 either the route to 0.0.0.0/0 or the route to 192.168.50.0/24 would be able to get the icmp packets where they need to go. Any pointers on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that this was a stupid question. I was so focused on the router that I didn't even look at my computer.

I had my computer's static IP configured as 192.168.10.1, but had forgotten to change the router config from 192.168.1.1 after finishing the initial config. I set the IP config on my PC to

IP: 192.168.10.10
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.10.1

Now I am about to ping 8.8.8.8 from my PC.